# How to use Flutter localization inside BLOC for translate messages?

Tags: flutter, localization, internationalization, translation

I am developing an app in Flutter. I'm using `flutter_localizations` package for localization and `intl` package for internationalization. For this, I'm using Context in Widgets, but the problem is when I want to use internationalization inside bloc or repositories or other layers except for the UI layer.

What is the best practice for doing internationalization inside Other layers except for UI where we don't have access to Context?

I have tried to use a Singleton, but I don't know if this is the right way.

Answer (score 2):

You have to pass appLocalizations. For example in the Cubits you can do something like:

main.dart

```
runApp(
 MaterialApp(
  localizationsDelegates: [
    AppLocalizations.delegate,
    GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
    GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
    GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
  ],
  supportedLocales: [
    const Locale('en', ''),
    const Locale('pl', ''),
  ],
  title: 'MySuperApp',
  debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
  theme: ThemeData(
    primarySwatch: Colors.orange,
    accentColor: Colors.deepOrangeAccent,
    visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
  ),
  initialRoute: '/',
  routes: {
    UserAuthScreen.routeName: (context) => const UserAuthScreen(),
    HomePage.routeName: (context) => HomePage(),
    ...
  }, 
  builder: (context, child) {
    final appLocalizations = AppLocalizations.of(context); //IMPORTANT
    return MultiBlocProvider(
      providers: [
        BlocProvider<ConstantsCubit>(
          lazy: true,
          create: (context) => ConstantsCubit(
            constantsRepository: ConstantsRepository(),
          ),
        ),
        BlocProvider<UserAuthCubit>(
          lazy: true,
          create: (context) => UserAuthCubit(
            localizations: appLocalizations, //THIS IS WHERE THE MAGIC HAPPENS
            repository: UserAuthRepository(),
          ),
        ),
        BlocProvider<DoerInfoCubit>(
            lazy: true,
            create: (context) => DoerInfoCubit(
                  doerInfoRepository: DoerInfoRepository(),
                  userAuthCubit: BlocProvider.of<UserAuthCubit>(context),
                )),
        ...
      ],
      child: child,
    );
  },
  home:
      BlocBuilder<UserAuthCubit, UserAuthState>(builder: (context, state) {
    if (state is UserAuthLogged) {
      return HomePage();
    } else {
      return const UserAuthScreen();
    }
  }),
),
);
```

In your bloc or cubit:

```
class UserAuthCubit extends Cubit<UserAuthState> {
 final UserAuthRepository repository;
 final AppLocalizations localizations; 

 UserAuthCubit({
   @required this.repository,
   @required this.localizations,
 }) : super(const UserAuthInitial()) {
   getUserAuthState();
 }
```

Comment: guys are you shure that this thing is ok to pass localization straight to bloc? My tech lead said that this is bad approach. What @rrousselGit could say about that?

Comment: generally speaking this is not a good idea https://stackoverflow.com/a/71887548/12041701

Answer (score 1):

Here's my approach for emitting localized messages via bloc/cubit.

Never ever pass applocalization in bloc, it will force app-restart when app locale changes, which is not good for UX. Always emit enums from bloc. then make a function to translate in view classes, that have legitimate access to BuildContext. Example are shown below:

```
 enum LoginValidationMessages {
  invalidEmailAddress,
  thisIsARequiredField,
  passwordLengthIsLessThan6,
  noError
}
```

Then in view:

```
 String? cubitEnumToLocalizedMessage(Enum? cubitEnum) {
  if (cubitEnum == null) return null;
  final l10n = context.l10n;
  switch (cubitEnum) {
    case LoginEnum.invalidEmailAddress:
      return l10n.invalidEmailAddress;
    case LoginEnum.thisIsARequiredField:
      return l10n.thisIsARequiredField;
    case LoginEnum.passwordLengthIsLessThan6:
      return l10n.passwordInvalid;
    default:
      return null;
  }
}
```